# Transfer rights from user to another user

Tags: postgresql, privileges, sql-grant

I have 3 tasks:

1. Create a database owner with 'sa' rights.
2. Create three database users.
3. Transfer the rights from the user from task 1 to one of the users from task 2.

I know how to solve first and second tasks:

```
CREATE USER admin WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password' SUPERUSER;
CREATE USER user1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'user1';
CREATE USER user2 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'user2';
CREATE USER user3 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'user3';
```

How can I solve third task?

Comment: What do you mean with `sa` rights? There is no such role (or user) in Postgres. But in genera, if you want to manage a certain set of privileges for multiple users, create a role, grant the privileges to that role, then grant the role to the users.

Comment: I meant `sa` like `superuser`. I didn't know that `sa` exists only in MsSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`grant`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) function:

```
GRANT admin TO user1;
```